# Turn on gps in android with user's permission directly from the android app

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am building an app which captures location by gps if gps is on and by network provider if gps is off. Now what i want is that when the user opens the app a pop up message should come which suggests that the app wants to switch on the gps for improved accuracy like in ola cab apps... the user has two options that is yes or no.... if the user clicks yes the gps turns on. How Do i do this??

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Services 7 introduced a way to open the GPS directly from the app.
See [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationSettings/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationsettings/MainActivity.java) from google for more information. The specific code block is

```
    protected void checkLocationSettings() {
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationSettingsRequest
            );
    result.setResultCallback(this);
}

/**
 * The callback invoked when
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsApi#checkLocationSettings(GoogleApiClient,
 * LocationSettingsRequest)} is called. Examines the
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult} object and determines if
 * location settings are adequate. If they are not, begins the process of presenting a location
 * settings dialog to the user.
 */
@Override
public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
    final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
            Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");
            startLocationUpdates();
            break;
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
            Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to" +
                    "upgrade location settings ");

            try {
                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                // in onActivityResult().
                status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
            }
            break;
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
            Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog " +
                    "not created.");
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Log.i(TAG, "User agreed to make required location settings changes.");
                    startLocationUpdates();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "User chose not to make required location settings changes.");
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

[Credit](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationSettings/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationsettings/MainActivity.java)